# Easily use Form Data for AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

While messing around with some UI it made me realize I feel like I do this backwards often.

In the HTML I have a form with some fields, and 'on submit' it does X.
I've gotten into the habit of after X starts, it assigns a variable to the val of each input.

Then I call the data dynamically. While this works, I feel like there is a better way to go about this.

**html**

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="charName" id="charName">
  <input type="text" name="charServer" id="charServer">
  <button type="button" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
</form>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#submitForm').click(function(){
    var myHeaders = new Headers();

var myInit = { method: 'POST',
               headers: myHeaders,
               mode: 'cors',
               cache: 'default' };
  var name = $("#charName").val();
  var server = $("#charServer").val();
  fetch('mySitesAPI'+server+'/'+name, myInit)
   .then(function(res){
     return res.text()
   }).then(function (res) {
    res = JSON.parse(res);
     $("#results").html("<div class='results'><div class='resName'>"
                        +res.name+"</div><div class='servName'>"
                        +res.realm+"</div><div class='resClass'>"
               +res.class+"</div><img src='linkToSiteForImages"
                        +res.thumbnail+"'/></div>");
     console.log(res)
   });
  });
});
```

I feel like if I'm doing something on the form button, shouldn't the data bind to it? Welcome suggestions/input. Also, I feel like the the method of res.test() then re-JSON.Parsing it is counter-intuitive but I had an issue of getting the data into the array other wise.

[Here is a CodePen for reference](http://codepen.io/dnorthrupva/pen/bwPMpX)

Note* I'm messing with the front-end section of my code a bit, so I'm using JS to pull data from my site. Which is the weird fetch() situation.

Comment: _"I feel like if I'm doing something on the form button, shouldn't the data bind to it"_ Not cure what you are trying to achieve? What is purpose using `.text()` then `JSON.parse()` ? Have you tried using `.json()`?

Comment: Instead of using JQ or JS to go into the field to pull data, how could you get the data to go with the form on submission?

For instance in PHP I'd just send 'data' on submit, and I could reference 'email' 'name' etc etc based on the name of the field.

Comment: You expect a response from server, yes? Then process response? What is issue with current approach?

Comment: Yes, it'll feed back an object. I think I understand what you're getting at, though. I'll try modifying the CodePen
Thanks for the .json() param - Completely got rid of that awkward redundancy.

Comment: @guest271314 It functions completely as it is. It's more of a question of 'Is this the practical way?' - I was wondering if by modifying the button type to 'submit' and changing the function req to 'on('submit') if it wouldn't already have the values of those two fields allocated in memory.

Comment: You would still need to reference the values to use current implementation. You could probably removing declaring variables and use `"mySitesAPI" + server + "/"+ $("#charServer").val() +"/" + $("#charName").val()`